# Flash Click Tag w SWFObject

Tags: flash, swfobject, clicktag

I hate flash, but one of our clients has sold a flash ad with a clickTAG and I can't get the click tag to work correctly. After vast searching and numerous attempts, I've got to:

```
<div id='flashdiv'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var flashvars = {}; 
flashvars.clickTAG = 'http://www.domain.com/track.asp?id=93';
var params = {};
var attributes = {}; 
var so = new SWFObject('/flash/ad_2013_728x90.swf', 'mymovie', '728', '90', '8', '#336699', flashvars, params, attributes);so.write('flashdiv');
</script>
```

This shows the ad correctly, the cursor is a pointer (the cursor was a pointer before I started implementing the clickTAG embed) but nothing happens when you click.

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I cracked it (notice the `so.addVariable`):

```
<div id='modestoflash'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var clickTag = escape('http://www.farmbusiness.cc/track.asp?id=93'); 
var so = new SWFObject('/flash/modesto_2013_728x90.swf', 'mymovie', '728', '90', '8');
so.addVariable('clickTag', clickTag);
so.write('modestoflash');
</script>
```